# Period of differences of $a_n = n, n \geq 2$ after first primes sieved.

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, integers, periodic-functions

Let $T \subset \Bbb{Z}$ be the first $N$ primes, and $a_n = n, n \geq 2$.  Define $\widehat{T}$ to be the sequence operator that deletes $a_m$ from $a$ if $p_k | m$ for some $k \leq N$.  Thus $\widehat{T}a$ starts on the prime $p_{N+1}$.  I've observed that $(\widehat{T}a)_n - (\widehat{T}a)_{n-1}$ is periodic for $N = 1, 2, 3, 4$, but have no idea how to compute the period or prove that it's always periodic, for all $N\geq 1$.

Any ideas?

Let $N = 2$.  Then $\widehat{T}a = 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 25, \dots$ with differences:

$2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, \dots$ so the period is $2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\displaystyle P = \prod_{k=1}^N p_k$. Then clearly any $a_m$ is removed from the sequence if and only if $a_{m+P}$ is removed from the sequence because for every $1 \leqslant k \leqslant N$: $p_k \mid m \iff p_k \mid m+P$.

Let $S = \# \{ n \in \mathbb{N} : 1 \leqslant (\widehat{T} a)_n \leqslant P \}$.

Then we prove $S = \# \{ n \in \mathbb{N} : A+1 \leqslant (\widehat{T} a)_n \leqslant A+P \}$ by induction on $A$.

Now fix $n$ and let $A+1 = (\widehat{T} a)_n$. Then $(\widehat{T} a)_n + P$ is the least element of the sequence $\widehat{T} a$ lying above the set $\{ n \in \mathbb{N} : A+1 \leqslant (\widehat{T} a)_n \leqslant A+P \}$ and to reach it we skip $S$ terms, so $(\widehat{T} a)_{n+S} = (\widehat{T} a)_n + P$.

Hence $(\widehat{T} a)_{n+S} - (\widehat{T} a)_{n+S-1} = (\widehat{T} a)_n - (\widehat{T} a)_{n-1}$, i.e. $(\widehat{T} a)_n - (\widehat{T} a)_{n-1}$ is periodic with period $S$.

Comment: I am in shock at how quickly and adeptly you came up with the answer.

Comment: @FruitfulApproach Thanks! I just saw it with the eyes of imagination. ^^